# Android 4.3 - No internet access, unable to connect to the proxy server error

Tags: proxy, mobile-network, 4.3-jelly-bean

My Lg nexus 4, received the android 4.3 update last night. I didn't do much on it, opting to sleep peacefully knowing that I had the latest and greatest in android software, but this morning I noticed that I cannot access the internet either via the web browser or the play market.

Chrome complains "unable to connect to the proxy server" regardless of what site I try to go to. And the play store says "No connection".

However, I do have a connection, I can use gmail to send and receive messages and I can use whatsapp and twitter and a few other apps.

I have checked the network settings for both my 3G and wifi, and there are no proxy settings or anything enabled.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

EDIT:

Does this happen on both WiFi and mobile data? YES

What apps have trouble, and which do work? Chrome and the play store as far as I can see are both troublesome. Other apps work i.e. my whatsapp can send/receive messages, twitter works and so on.

What's the color of your signal bars in the notification area? Blue, full signal on HSDPA.

EDIT 2:
I think this may be affected by some setting left over from a rogue app. I have played with VPN apps and proxy setting apps in the past (a few months ago) so perhaps the new 4.3 update read some of those settings and configured things incorrectly?

Comment: Can you please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/50273/edit) your question, and add some more details: Does this happen on both, WiFi and mobile data? What apps have trouble, and which do work? (i.e. is Chrome the only failing app? Have you tried other browsers?) What's the color of your signal bars in the notification area (though if GMail works, they are most likely blue)?

Comment: I've the same problem. Chrome, Firefox, Facebook & others think I've a proxy configured, but I can't find the setting to remove it. Some other apps work fine. I also played around with proxies before, but as soon as I booted into 4.3 this started happening.

Comment: Any solution to this issue? I have the same problem after upgrade to 4.3

Comment: I might have a solution, but unable to answer my own question as I dont have 10 reputation on here. Need some people to like my question before I can reply.

Comment: @Husman Sure you can answer. Also, you have 106 rep.

Comment: i need 10 from this site. I think I only have 6 from here and I got a hundred for coming here from stackoverflow.  The reply button is still disabled.

Comment: @geffchang http://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation "If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions"

Comment: Gave you an upvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have cleared your Google Service Framework data to receive the update, it will change your device ID that Google uses to recognise your device. This also affects the tokens used by some apps (i.e. Google Now, Google Search, Chrome) and they won't connect to the Google servers properly and refuse to work for a while (this was like 24~48 hours for me, before these apps started behaving as the tokens were eventually refreshed). Other non-Google apps will continue working.

More details of why this happens can be found in this reddit post by a Google engineer:
https://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/20/google-engineer-dan-morrill-sheds-some-light-on-the-nexus-ota-process-urges-you-to-never-clear-google-service-framework-data/